# Python sorting multiple tuples

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am using python for image matching.  The feature vectors for reference images is stored in a mysql database. For every new image, i generate the feature vector, find the difference between the test image and the reference vectors in mysql db and return the matches based on distance.  This is working well.  However, I want to sort the results based on the distance and get only the top 10 results that has the highest distance.  My code so far is as follows:

```
for i,a in enumerate(data):
    features=[float(x) for x in a[6:]]
    d = chi2_distance(features, queryFeatures)
    results=a[1],d
    #res=sorted(results, key=itemgetter(1))
    #results.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    #results=sorted(results,key=lambda x: x[1])
    #results=sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    print(type(results))
```

When I print type of results i get the following:

```
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'tuple'>
```

When I print just the results, I get:

```
(127209905L, 6.459347693123215)
(127281515L, 7.790508647801378)
(127312977L, 6.374409391826666)
```

I tried various methods including, converting the tuples to list and then sorting by list, but none of them worked.  I am relatively a new bee working on python...any guidance on how to go about this would be very helpful.

The expected output is

```
(127281515L, 7.790508647801378)
(127209905L, 6.459347693123215)
(127312977L, 6.374409391826666)
```

Comment: @Rakesh added the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, instead of

```
results=a[1],d
```

use

```
results.append((a[1], d))
```

to collect all the data. And then

```
results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

to sort results based on distance.

Comment: I think based on example output should add `reverse=True` argument.

Comment: @thesilkworm Thanks

Comment: @ravi thank you...i worked.  My mistake was....I used `results={}` as a dict and not as a list `[]`.